# SQL QUERY Append Two Columns

Tags: sql

I am still learning on SQL Statements
How do I append two columns?

E.g

```
Table 1

    | ID | Name      | Position  | 
    ------------------------------
    | 1  | Mike      | Developer
    | 2  | Mark      | QA        |
```

Expected Result

```
Table 2
    
    | ID | User Role/Name |
    -----------------------
    | 1  | Mike           |
    | 1  | Developer      |
    | 2  | Mark           |
    | 2  | QA             |
    -----------------------
```

Comment: Just to clarify - is "Table 1" the table you have and "Table 2" the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Yes Mureinik and  Roshan Twanabasu. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use union all:

```
select ID, Name as "User Role/Name" from table1
union all
select ID, position from table1
order by ID
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f3cb943f7b437c41ed6e881540fcea32)

Answer (score 0):

Do you means that it will output like it?

```sql
select ID, concat(Position,'/',Name) from Table2
```

```
| ID | User Role/Name |
-----------------------
| 1  | Developer/Mike |
| 2  | QA/Mark        |
```